# SQL wildcards: Dictating amount of characters and values for each character

Tags: sql, regex, database, wildcard

I want to look for a very specific substring which is between 3 and 5 characters. Each character can be numeric [0-9] or [a-z].

The substring I'm looking for is either a word or number. I know how to dictate the exact amount of chars with "_" and using "[]" to tell sql what characters
I'm looking for but how do I mix them?

I've tried all kind of nonsense but nothing worked.

Comment: Provide example data set and SQL you had tried.

Comment: Also - what RDBMS are you using?

Comment: @Mureinik . . . I would guess SQL Server based on the use of `_` as a wildcard.  But the OP should tag appropriately.

Comment: sorry, i forgot. i am using sybase as rdbms.

Comment: i tried  declare @abc varchar(100)              select @abc='Book [a-z]%[________]'                       problem is that sql wont take my brackets as wildcard in apostrophes...and not sure if code combination works lol

Answer (score 0):

This is dirty but it works (at least in c# ):

```
\b\w{3}\b|\b\w{4}|\b\\bw{5}\b
```

You can replace \w with [A-Za-z0-9] if you need to, \w also includes _